# CSV File Formatting With VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the code below to push out a worksheet and save it as a .csv with specific formatting to dates and values.  Everything works great but the Program that uploads (I think its an Oracle based database) is giving me the error that the column count is not correct.  This is not really the case and a common error I am trying to eliminate from the process. When the file is opened and the formatting is applied manually and saved the file is accepted and loaded.  Is there some specific command in the saving process that will retain the formatting when it comes to saving a .csv file?  Maybe it's the Save AS.

Thanks!

```
Dim wsNT As Worksheet
Set wsNT = Worksheets("Upload")
Dim Box As String
Box = InputBox(WhatFile, "File Name", ToSave & "_#")

SaveToDirectory = "\\SomeFilePath\"
SaveToDirectory3 = "\\AnotherFilePath\"

wsNT.Copy

 Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "MMMM YYYY"
 Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "MMMM YYYY"
 Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "###0.00_)"
 Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "###0.00_)"


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "\" & Box & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory3 & "\" & Box & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your error with Oracle, but I have typically seen database errors like "invalid column count" (is that what you're seeing?") when importing plain text data files.  IIRC, it's typically because your data contains some characters which are problematic with the database application, or which are "corrupting" the file's expected structure (new line/carriage returns especially will do this...)

Comment: As for "formatting", a CSV file doesn't preserve formatting. A CSV file is a plain text file that is delimited by commas, hence the name "Comma Separated Values". While you can apply formatting in Excel, it's not possible to apply these formats in any sort of persistent state because the CSV file itself simply doesn't support formatting at all..

Comment: When OP refers to "formatting", it looks like they're talking about the date and number formats, rather than things like fonts and shading. The actual letters and numbers used to represent a date ARE things that can be preserved in a CSV.

Comment: Yes I am strictly curious about the "formatting" of the Date and Number columns.  As I mentioned earlier when these columns are formatted manually and the file is saved the file loads with no issue leading me to believe the VBA initiated formatting is not being saved.  I know that the formatting is getting accomplished in the program, I have verified that.

Comment: Have you looked at it in a text editor to verify how they are being output?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Problem was in the formatting of the numeric values we were trying to load:  instead of "###0.00_)"  we used "0.00"